# How to create and pass IConfiguration using MSTest

Tags: c#, moq, mstest

I have a concrete service that is declared in the form:

```
public class ApiDataService:IApiDataService
{
    private IConfiguration configuration;
    public ApiDataService(IConfiguration _configuration)
    {
        configuration = _configuration;
    }......
```

I'm trying to write a test method uising MsTest to test one of it's methods, but I'm having trouble initializing the class. As part of the test I need to get a value from the config file.

My initial thought was to declare a couple of mocks.:

```
private Mock<IConfiguration> _configuration = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
private Mock<IConfigurationSection> _configSection = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();

ApiDataService _apiDataService { get; set; }
```

and then in the `[TestInitialize]` section set up the values and then create the new service.

```
_apiDataService = new ApiDataService(_configuration);
```

However I receive:

> Cant convert `Mock<IConfiguration>` to IConfiguration.

Comment: it should be `new ApiDataService(_configuration.Value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gladly yo don't need to mock the `IConfiguration` and `IConfigurationSection` interfaces.

Rather than you can create an in-memory configuration, like this:

```
IConfiguration configRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "SingleKey", "Value" }, 
        { "ArrayOfValues:0", "Value1" },
        { "ArrayOfValues:1", "Value2" },
        { "ArrayOfValues:2", "Value3" }
    })
    .Build();
```

And you can pass this object to your `ApiDataService` ctor.